# Query another table with results of an another query that include a csv column

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Brief Summary:**

I am currently trying to get a count of completed parts that fall within a specific time range, machine number, operation number, and matches the tool number.

**For example:**

```
SELECT Sequence, Serial, Operation,Machine,DateTime,value as Tool
FROM tbPartProfile
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tool_Used, ',')
ORDER BY DateTime desc
```

[image]

is running a query which pulls all the instances that a tool has been changed, I am splitting the CSV from Tool_Used column.  I am doing this because there can be multiple changes during one operation.

**Objective:**
This is where the production count come into place.  For example, record 1 has a to0l change of 36 on 12/12/2022.  I will need to go back in to the table and get the amount of part completed that equals the OPERATION/MACHINE/TOOL and fall between the date range.

**For example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbPartProfile
WHERE Operation = 20 AND Machine = 1 AND Tool_Used LIKE '%36%'
ORDER BY DateTime desc
```

[image]

For example this query will give me the datetimes the tools LIKE 36 was changed.  I will need to take this datetime and compare it previous query and get the sum of all parts that were ran in this TimeRange/Operation/Machine/Tool Used

Comment: What happens when your `like %36%` finds `136` or `360` etc ?

Comment: Yup this is an issue which I am aware of it was just an example because I did not break CSV column

Comment: The real question is why are you storing delimited data? Why not normalise your design?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Your query seems only to be missing the date-range condition `AND [DateTime] < '2022-12-12 12:58:35.763'` or perhaps `AND [DateTime] >= @PriorChange AND [DateTime] < @CurrentChange` and a `COUNT(*)` in you select.

Comment: @Larnu This is a legacy database that runs a reporting app